# Is there a shorter version of saying "これからは、日本語を学ぶために全力を尽くします。"?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I want to say this sentence in Nihongo:

> "From now on, I will do my best to learn Japanese."

I entered the exact same sentence in Google Translate and it gave me:

> これからは、日本語を学ぶために全力を尽くします。

But I am also aware that Google Translate sometimes has grammatical errors in its result. I can confirm that **これからは** is the correct translation for **from now on**, since I often hear that in anime episodes, but I am not sure if the rest of the sentence is correct.

Please help me confirm if the rest of it is grammatically correct, or if there's something wrong with it. Also, is there a shorter version of saying this in Nihongo? I feel like this translation is too long. Thank you very much.

**Background:**

I am very new to learning Japanese. I am learning it for two reasons:

- to communicate well with my new Japanese friends and clients
- to fulfill my dream of learning as many languages as I can

Comment: Usually if I hear "google translate" and "Japanese to English", I expect something pretty terrible. In all honesty, this is a pretty legitimate and natural Japanese expression for the English you supplied.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to say the same sentence in a much shorter version?

Comment: Thank you. That one sounds simpler. Am I correct that ベスト is some kind of a borrowed word?

Comment: Also, If you can add your comment as an answer below, I would be glad to accept it as the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "From now on, I will do my best to learn Japanese."
>   これからは、日本語を学ぶために全力を尽くします。

When we learn English language, we Japanese usually say not 英語｛えいご｝を学｛まな｝ぶ, but say 英語｛えいご｝を勉強｛べんきょう｝する. And, the translation of 全力｛ぜんりょく｝を尽｛つ｝くす for "to do one's best" is correct, but it doesn't sound natural.  So, I recommend you to say 一生｛いっしょう｝懸命｛けんめい｝/一所｛いっしょ｝懸命｛けんんめい｝～をする. So the appropriate translation for "From now on, I will do my best to learn Japanese."  is;

> これからは、日本語｛にほんご｝を勉強｛べんきょう｝します＋ to do one's best ＝　これからは、日本語｛にほんご｝を一生｛いっしょう｝懸命｛けんめい｝/一所｛いっしょ｝懸命｛けんめい｝勉強｛べんきょう｝します。

By the way, I'll show you the usage difference between 「全力を尽くす」 and 「一生懸命／一所懸命～をする」. The principal difference lies in the duration time of doing effort.
As for the former phrase, someone does his best only once or for a short period of time just like "doing one's best in the tennis match", while for the latter phrase, someone does one's best for a long period of time just like "doing one's best in learning Japanese."

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very helpful, not only for this particular sentence. I will keep this in mind :)